# Python and Selenium WebDriver not entering text in the correct text box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.8

I am trying to write an instagram bot with python and selenium, and I am having trouble getting the bot to login to instagram. Whenever it tries to enter the username and password to log in, it will enter the username, then go to the password box and enter the first two or three characters then go back and enter the rest in the username box.

[gif showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sErZO.gif)

I have tried various solutions and so far the only successful way has been to use javascript to fill the boxes, but that method was very clunky and had an issue with the "Log in" button not being clickable, so if I can get this method to work I would be very happy.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python3

import time
from selenium import webdriver


class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, passwd):
        self.username = username
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path="/usr/bin/safaridriver")
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")    # load instagram login
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]").send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]").send_keys(passwd)
        # self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.quit()    # close browser window


InstaBot("username", "P4$$w0rd")
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I executed your code, and I have no issue though

Comment: Try clicking on the element once, before send_keys.

Comment: I tried the clicking already. I forgot to mention that in the post. Sorry. @dpapadopoulos did you use safari as the browser? is it possible that that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I just tried downloading and using Firefox instead and that seems to have done it. I can enter the username and password in the correct text boxes and it clicks the login button with no errors now so I guess that there was something going on with using safari. I don't know why but now it's working. So if anyone else sees this thread and is having this problem, try a different browser since that seems to have worked for me.